# Deprecated web component widgets not displaying in Wakanda 1.0.3+

Tags: widget, deprecated, web-component, display, wakanda

With no console errors or messages, and only from Wakanda 1.0.3 forward, I have found that a bunch (but not all) of deprecated widgets (text, text input for example) are not displaying (Chrome and Safari latest versions) within web components.  Wakanda Server on OS X 10.11.4.

I replace Wakanda 1.0.3 with 1.0.2 and there is no issue.  I reload 1.0.3, or even 1.1.0, and the issue persists.

I am hoping that this 3 year mature application does not require me to go in and replace all of the deprecated widgets with the newer ones?

Anybody experiencing this issue, and can you provide considerations or suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, *when an object is deprecated, that means you will need to replace it with something else. It is better to do it sooner rather then later.*

#### Deprecated

Wikipedia describes [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) as:

> Deprecation is the discouragement of use of some feature, design or practice, typically because it has been superseded or is no longer considered safe, without (at least for the time being) removing it from the system of which it is a part or prohibiting its use.

---

Regarding the widgets not working without any warning or message in the console; it looks like you did [file a bug](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/55); but then later [closed the bug](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/55#issuecomment-218012515) after finding it was working in the latest pre-release.

Comment: Wish it were that simple.  1.0.1 no issue.  1.0.2 no issue.  1.0.3 and 1.1.0 issue shows up within web components only.  Imagine the number of applications out there with text input widgets from the past 3 years of Wakanda.

Comment: As further info on the topic of deprecation, I would suggest you consider the path of WAF in general. The entire WAF framework was described as deprecated in a recent webinar. That includes v2 widgets.

They did distinguish "support" was still ongoing, but clearly said no features would be added:

http://www.appfactory.tk/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=17#p17

Comment: Greg,  your reply brings a bit of "panic."  To get clarity, what are you saying for those of us who have worked since early versions like Wak5, have mature and leveraged applications, and have tons of pages in our apps that leverage the range of widgets available via Studio?

Comment: And would I be accurate in suggesting that today (versus a year ago), the level of formal support and responsiveness to issues like (widgets not functioning in the current release) ... has changed significantly from the days of the Premium forum (which I had previously classified as some of the best responsiveness I have seen in my career)?

Comment: Reminder: Premium Support **is** available at [support.wakanda.io](https://support.wakanda.io)

Comment: What about for apps that are private and not on the Cloud?  The above is only for cloud hosted Wakanda apps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with growing focus on Wakanda-AngularJS and stuff for mobile applications, original Wakanda widgets might fall apart to category of non-perspective and even obsolete.

I am absolutely convinced that Wakanda team should continue supporting them for those who focuses on backoffice tasks and quick prototyping. Wakanda widgets are perfect when it comes to organizing back office on Web quick and easy.

For Wakanda-AngularJS we need the same WYSISWYG drag-and-drop approach for backoffice related tasks.